# "he stepped down as leader in favor of his rival" what does this mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Does it mean that "he stepped down because his rival becomed the leader"?
Does "as" here mean "because"?
Does "in favor of" here mean "be replaced with"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the leader of some group or organisation resigned his position in order to allow a rival to take over, possibly to avoid a divisive internal battle.

This sometimes happens in the real world when the leader wishes to avoid such a struggle, or is persuaded that it is in his/her interest, or the organisation's, to do so.

Answer (score 0):

He resigned **[to the advantage of (b)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-favor-of)** his opponent.